# SD Card not mounting after reboot

Tags: storage, reboot, mount

My Android doesn't mount my SD Card after reboot. I need to get out the SD Card slot and put it back in. Can I fix this?

By the way I have a Samsung Galaxy J7 (2017).

Comment: How large is the SD-card and is it formatted with FAT32 or exFAT format. Some devices have problems with exFAT file system. In such a case you can reformat (deletes all data) by the phone itself. Therefore the phone can decide which format is preferred.

Comment: It works just fine, I have a lot of apps on it. The problem is that android doesnt detect it. It detects it only after I reinsert it

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting another SD card in your phone if it does that means there is problem with your SD card

Try opening the same SDcard in your laptop and see if opens copy the data and format...if it doesnt open try formatting it and then insert in your phone

Comment: It does the same for another SD Card. I tried to go into settings to mount it manually there and it says that I dont have any sd card in my slot

Comment: I have a lot of apps that I cant move on my phone because I dont have enough storage.

Comment: That means either there is a problem with your card slot or your software. Are u running any custom ROMS or the stock rom ? Try backing up your files to desktop and resettting your phone

Comment: I am running the original Android 8.1.0 that my phone came with.